# What does "were to be" mean? Is that some kind of a tense?

Tags: conditionals

Consider the following sentence, from "*Introduction to Control Systems*" by Malgorzata Zywno:

> Note that if a summer **were to be** moved behind the block, the additional gain would be equal the value of the block gain, instead of its inverse.
>
> [bold mine]

What does "were to be" mean there? As far as I know, this is a second-type conditional sentence, and there should be "*was*" there (not "*were*", as the subject is "*summer*", which is 3rd person singular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the word "if",  this is a conditional clause with an "unreal" condition.  The summer isn't, and won't be moved behind the block.  The sentence is considering a hypothetical situation.

This allows the change from "was" to "were".  It is sometimes called a "were subjunctive" or "were irrealis"

The grammar, therefore has a linking verb "were" with a infinitive complement "to be moved behind the block".
This infinitive contains a passive construction "be moved"

We can try to understand this by first rewriting as active

> If someone were to move a summer behind a block...

And removing the irrealis

> If someone moves a summer behind a block...

This simplified sentence has a similar meaning, but is a "real" condition (the speaker supposes that it is possible or probable to occur)

Comment: And what is the difference between "were to move" and "moved"?